# Auto assign an Entitlement to a specific record type case

Tags: trigger, record-type, developer, entitlements, entitlement-process

I am looking to auto assign a particular entitlement process to all cases of a particular record type once the case is created. The case page layout contains an Entitlement Name field which is used as a look up to the entitlement processes that the agents currently use to manually assign an entitlement to a case. How can I accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it correctly, you want to auto assign entitlement for a particular type of cases. You can achieve this using trigger. "EntitlementId" field in case is used to assign entitlements to case.

In your code you can check if record type is matching, you can populate that entitlement in case. You can refer to below article.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.entitlements_auto_add.htm&type=5

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you I will try this out. I am not experienced in developing in Apex. Is there an alternative rather than using code? appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, you can use flows. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: thank you Muzammil. Have you got any resources that I could work with to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have provided link in answer, you can refer to that fir logic and implement the same in flow.

Comment: Thank you I have managed to achieve this using Process Builder to assign the Entitelment ID to a particular record type once the case is created

Comment: I would suggest you to go for flow instead of process builder as salesforce is going to retire process builder very soon.